# xrandr pixels cut off on high refresh rate

Tags: xrandr, multi-monitor

I've just got a USB-C dock for my laptop (DP1.4) capable of driving both my displays: a 1440p 165Hz monitor and a 1080p 60Hz monitor. Both are PC monitors, not TVs, and don't have overscan. I have turned off my internal laptop display.

The following works as expected:

```
xrandr --output eDP --off --output DisplayPort-1 --mode 2560x1440 --rate 60 --primary --output DisplayPort-2 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60.00 --right-of DisplayPort-1
```

I would like to step my 1440p monitor up to 120Hz.

```
xrandr --output eDP --off --output DisplayPort-1 --mode 2560x1440 --rate 120 --primary --output DisplayPort-2 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60.00 --right-of DisplayPort-1
```

The above displays my screen *almost perfectly* however with a narrow band of pixels missing from the left-hand side of my 1440p display, likely around 4. It is as if the display has shifted 1 or 2 pixels to the left. There are no other issues and 120Hz works as expected.

This issue persists when turning off the second monitor and just attempting to drive the 1440p monitor. It additionally persists when attempting to drive the primary monitor only at 144Hz - the maximum offered by xrandr with this dock.

Any advice on where to start with this? Thanks!